# Big variations in measured performance on Windows 7 system

Tags: c, performance, windows-7

I am trying to do some performance enhancements to a Windows console mode application (written in C under VS 2012 Express), looking for perhaps 20% or so to win a competitive benchmark. I am being defeated by the huge variation in measured performance of the software where repeating the exact same test can yield results that differ by as much as 100% of the best time (I have seen even more).

The test is running under Windows 7 Pro on a quad core 2.7GHz processor. There are no other processes running that are consuming any significant system power.

The program is largely concerned with character string manipulation. There is no i/o aside from reporting the result but there is heavy use of malloc() and free(). The program has a second thread that will be idle throughout this test.

I am measuring performance by using the GetProcessTimes() function to record processor time in a test that takes around 5 seconds. Measuring elapsed time instead produces the same behaviour. It is also clear that this is a genuine performance difference, not an inaccuracy in the measurement technique.

Interestingly, running the program multiple times from the same Command Prompt window yields a reasonably close (but still unexplained) variation in performance. Opening a new Command Prompt window sometimes yields significantly different performance but repeating the test in the same instance of the Command Prompt window produces reasonably consistent results.

This is crazy. Why should the parent process have any bearing on the performance of its child process?

I am aware that the system adjusts the processor speed automatically according to the load on the system. The best I can do is to repeat the test under identical conditions in the hope that the processor will be running at broadly the same speed each time. I have tried inserting a lengthy CP intensive loop before the timed section of the program so that the processor can settle on an appropriate speed. As expected, the Task Manager shows that my process is consuming 25% of the available processor power.

I have also read the related questions on performance variation but none of them seem to explain what I am seeing.

In trying to track this down, I have noticed that the process is generating an enormous number of soft page faults. The Windows Task Manager shows a page fault delta that is typically over 400,000. I have read countless articles about page faults, most of which say that soft page faults can be ignored but this value seems high enough that it must surely have a performance impact. This opinion is supported by the page fault delta being much lower when the performance is at its best.

So, my questions are: (1) Why do I see big variations in performance of the exact same program and (2) Is there some monitoring tool that might explain the very high soft page faults?

All ideas much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can get a performance gain by using static arrays instead of heavy `malloc` and `free` usage, which presumably is the real objective. In these circumstances I use the simpler `clock()` function called at the start and the end of the program. Although on Windows this gives wall time, it is still a good indication of how I am doing, especially when the target computer checking my submission usually runs faster than my own. Having said that, my execution times are never consistent.

Comment: May this could be useful: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor

Comment: The article looks interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but use of static arrays is not an option. To put this into context, the software concerned is our commercial database package and the benchmark is doing extensive string manipulation where the string sizes cannot be predicted in advance. The linked article perhaps explains some of the variability of measured performance but leaves the question of why I see such a huge soft page fault delta and why running the program from different Command Prompt windows sometimes yields very different figures but consistent within each window.